# Writing CUDA surface backed by an array of vectors

Tags: vector, cuda, surface

I am trying to write to a 2-dimensional cudaArray through a `surface<void, 2>`.
The array has a channel format `{32, 32, 0, 0, cudaChannelFormatKindFloat}` or to put it more simply, holds `vector2`s.

I am trying to write a `vector2` to the surface at the position indicated by integer coordinates `(x, y)`. The following works well:

```
// write the float2 vector d to outSurf
surf2Dwrite(d.x, outSurf, x * sizeof(float2), y);
surf2Dwrite(d.y, outSurf, x * sizeof(float2) + sizeof(float), y);
```

However, if I do

```
surf2Dwrite(d, outSurf, x * sizeof(float2), y);
```

only the `x` component of the vector is being written. *What is the reason for this slightly unintuitive behaviour?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it hard to believe that any of those surf2Dwrite calls actually do what you think they do. To write a `float2` I would use this:

```
surf2Dwrite<float2>(d, outSurf, x, y);
```

The x and y arguments are the coordinates on the surface you are writing to and the template parameter tells the call the size of the type being accessed.

Comment: That was the problem. Although I wonder why letting Type = vector2 couldn't be deduced from the arguments by the compiler.

Comment: Section 3.2.10.2.2 of the CUDA C Programming Guide (4.0) says that surfaces use byte-addressing for the x coordinate, so multiplication of `x` by `sizeof(float2)` is still needed, although.